# Replicating child elements in JavaScript [Bug]

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to solve a problem for an assignment, where the objective is to build a game. The game loads with smiley faces shown across two columns(divs) laid out side by side. There is one extra smiley on the left div, and if the user clicks on that extra smiley, the next run of the game should:

1. Increase the number of smileys by 5, for the next run
2. Generate a whole new set of smileys for the second run(by removing existing smileys from the current run).

The code I have so far has a bug. If I include the code for removing child nodes from the current run of the game, in the next run 5 more smileys are not added. If I remove this code, then in the next run, 5 more smileys are added but the previous smileys are at the same position (meaning they are not removed).

Here's the JS code:

```
var numberOfFaces = 5;
    var theLeftSide = document.getElementById("leftSide");
    var theRightSide = document.getElementById("rightSide");
    var theBody = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];


    function generateFaces() {

        //remove current children
        while(theLeftSide.firstChild){
                theLeftSide.removeChild(theLeftSide.firstChild);
            }

        while(theRightSide.firstChild){
                theRightSide.removeChild(theRightSide.firstChild);
            }

        while(numberOfFaces > 0) {
            var face = document.createElement("img");
            face.src = "http://home.cse.ust.hk/~rossiter/mooc/matching_game/smile.png";
            var topValue = generateRandomNumber(0,400);
            face.style.top = topValue+"px";
            var leftValue = generateRandomNumber(0,400);
            face.style.left = leftValue+"px";
            theLeftSide.appendChild(face);

            //changes
            var leftSideImages = theLeftSide.cloneNode(true);
            var leftSideLastImage = leftSideImages.lastChild;
            leftSideImages.removeChild(leftSideLastImage);
            theRightSide.appendChild(leftSideImages);


            //4th - generate 5 more faces for correct click in left side
            theLeftSide.lastChild.onclick = function nextLevel(event){
                event.stopPropagation();
                numberOfFaces += 5;
                generateFaces();
            };

            theBody.onclick = function gameOver() {
                alert("Game Over!");
                theBody.onclick = null;
                theLeftSide.lastChild.onclick = null;
            }; 

            numberOfFaces--;
        }

    }


    function generateRandomNumber(min, max) {
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max-min + 1));
    }
```

And this is the link to the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d8knj6yj/1/).

I also made a [Codepen](http://codepen.io/Nyxx/pen/mVdQrL) pen that has the same code.

Would appreciate any help.

---

Update -

My function structure was somewhat different in earlier attempts. I revised it based on some forum comments. Here's the earlier structure-

```
function generateFaces() {

    //remove current children
    while(theLeftSide.firstChild){
            theLeftSide.removeChild(theLeftSide.firstChild);
        }

    while(theRightSide.firstChild){
            theRightSide.removeChild(theRightSide.firstChild);
        }

    while(numberOfFaces > 0) {
        var face = document.createElement("img");
        face.src = "http://home.cse.ust.hk/~rossiter/mooc/matching_game/smile.png";
        var topValue = generateRandomNumber(0,400);
        face.style.top = topValue+"px";
        var leftValue = generateRandomNumber(0,400);
        face.style.left = leftValue+"px";
        theLeftSide.appendChild(face);
        numberOfFaces--;
    }

        //changes
        var leftSideImages = theLeftSide.cloneNode(true);
        var leftSideLastImage = leftSideImages.lastChild;
        leftSideImages.removeChild(leftSideLastImage);
        theRightSide.appendChild(leftSideImages);


        //4th - generate 5 more faces for correct click in left side
        theLeftSide.lastChild.onclick = function nextLevel(event){
            event.stopPropagation();
            numberOfFaces += 5;
            generateFaces();
        };

        theBody.onclick = function gameOver() {
            alert("Game Over!");
            theBody.onclick = null;
            theLeftSide.lastChild.onclick = null;
        }; 

        //numberOfFaces--;


}
```

Comment: Your fiddle works like a charm for me, as soon as you call the `generateFaces()` function after the definition, look here http://jsfiddle.net/1a91858p/

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. I had a `<body onload="generateFaces()">` at the top, looks like that wasn't included in JSFiddle somehow. But even without that, if you simply call `generateFaces()` at the end - the problem remains the same. You get 5 new smileys (at different positions) if you click on the smiley correctly - but it should be 5 **more** smileys instead of just 5 smileys! That's what is not working right now.

Comment: ok, got it. and they all (old 5 and new 5) are at new positions?

Comment: My apologies since the question isn't clear. Yes, all smileys(old 5 and new 5) are at new positions. Here's what every correct run of the game would do - redraw the existing set of smileys at new positions and add 5 more smileys to this, such that with the first run you have 5 smileys, for the next correct run you have 10 smileys, and so on. In the second run, the first 5 smileys would be redrawn(at random positions) and another 5 smileys would be added to the set. This continues with every loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are decrementing `numberOfFaces` to zero in the while loop and add 5 again, so the value is always 5.

Change the while loop to

```
for(var n = 0; n < numberOfFaces; n++) {
    var face = document.createElement("img");
    face.src = "http://home.cse.ust.hk/~rossiter/mooc/matching_game/smile.png";
    var topValue = generateRandomNumber(0,400);
    face.style.top = topValue+"px";
    var leftValue = generateRandomNumber(0,400);
    face.style.left = leftValue+"px";
    theLeftSide.appendChild(face);


    ...
}
```

and each run adds an extra 5 smiley set. Altered fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/1a91858p/3/)

Comment: Many thanks! I wonder why I didn't see that. Every time `numberOfFaces` becomes 5, as it's a global variable, so only 5 faces are shown. Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

Append your right child after while loop:

```
    var numberOfFaces = 5;
    var theLeftSide = document.getElementById("leftSide");
    var theRightSide = document.getElementById("rightSide");
    var theBody = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];


    function generateFaces() {

        //remove current children
        while(theLeftSide.firstChild){
                theLeftSide.removeChild(theLeftSide.firstChild);
            }

        while(theRightSide.firstChild){
                theRightSide.removeChild(theRightSide.firstChild);
            }

        while(numberOfFaces > 0) {
            var face = document.createElement("img");
      face.setAttribute("src", "http://home.cse.ust.hk/~rossiter/mooc/matching_game/smile.png");
            //face.src = "http://home.cse.ust.hk/~rossiter/mooc/matching_game/smile.png";
            var topValue = generateRandomNumber(0,400);
            face.style.top = topValue+"px";
            var leftValue = generateRandomNumber(0,400);
            face.style.left = leftValue+"px";
            theLeftSide.appendChild(face);

            //changes
            var leftSideImages = theLeftSide.cloneNode(true);
            var leftSideLastImage = leftSideImages.lastChild;
            leftSideImages.removeChild(leftSideLastImage);



            //4th - generate 5 more faces for correct click in left side
            theLeftSide.lastChild.onclick = function nextLevel(event){
                event.stopPropagation();
                numberOfFaces += 5;
                generateFaces();
            };

            theBody.onclick = function gameOver() {
                alert("Game Over!");
                theBody.onclick = null;
                theLeftSide.lastChild.onclick = null;
            }; 

            numberOfFaces--;
        }
        theRightSide.appendChild(leftSideImages);
    }


    function generateRandomNumber(min, max) {
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max-min + 1));
    }
```

Check out [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xZxmYy)

Comment: Umm- that's not exactly what the issue is. Even without the append of right child after while loop, I did get 5 new smileys at every subsequent run. But the bug is that I am required to get 5 **more** smileys with every correct run of the game, thereby making the level of the game harder. I had written this line just for that - `numberOfFaces += 5;` But only 5 new smileys are generated and displayed with every correct run of the game. What should happen is that every correct run of the game should regenerate the old smileys at new positions and generate 5 new smileys as well.